# AutoFit to content in Bi publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

is it possible to Auto Fit to the Content in Bi publisher

I have like max 30 Column and max of 30 Character length 
I want the Cells to be Auto_Fit

Can this be done using on-line Layout Report Design or using RTF(Word Template)

**Note**:**Excel template is not an option as HTML Preview is required** and Excel Template Doesn't Support UI i.e. HTML preview of data in the report.please help me .gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Word to make an RTF template, you can specify a tables column width.  The additional text would just wrap down.

Alternately you can do a sub-string of the first 30 characters of a field.

```
<?xdofx:substr(ELEMENT_NAME,START_POSITION,LENGTH)?>  

<?xdofx:substr(ELEMENT_NAME,1,30)?>
```